# Can Dockerfile commands be lowercase?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I wonder if Dockerfile commands can be written in lowercase (or have different cases for each letter, f.e. camelCase)?

P.S.: I searched the docs and previous questions on stackoverflow. Since I didn't find an answer I decided to ask here.

Comment: Why not try it out and see what happens?

Comment: I just don't want to repeat someone's mistakes/explorations, but get knowledge from learning their experiences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#format)

> Here is the format of the Dockerfile:

```
# Comment
INSTRUCTION arguments
```

> The instruction is not case-sensitive. However, convention is for them to be UPPERCASE to > distinguish them from arguments more easily.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can write instructions in lowercase.

It is just a recommendation/notion so that Dockerfile instructions can be differentiated from the commands/arguments that you wish to run in that Dockerfile.